# How to unload a vim script after sourcing it and making changes to it?

Tags: vim, plugins, vim-plugin

I'm writing a small vim plugin and `:source %`-ing the .vim file as I make incremental changes.

After each change and `:source` command, the newest changes don't seem to be loaded/applied, so I'd like to un-`:source`/unload the file somehow without closing and reopening VIm.

Is there a (better) way to do this? What should be the right workflow when writing a VIm plugin and trying the new functionality?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "unloading" a Vim script.  The best you can do is write your script in such a way that a reload does all relevant initialisation regardless of the the previous state.  E.g. use `function!` instead of `function`, `command!` instead of `command`, use `augroup`s etc.

Comment: Thanks. @SatoKatsura, By reload you mean sourcing the script file again, without restarting VIm?

Comment: Yes. That's pretty much the best you can do.

Comment: If you define dictionaries with functions (in order to emulate OO programming), you'll also have to have the member functions point to non-anonymous functions. You'll also have to anticipate the need to ignore the anti-reinclusion guard if you're using one. Last thing if you want to remove stuff (commands, mappings, etc) then you'll have to do it manually. Overriding previous definitions is easy. Removing isn't.

Answer (score 7):

In order to sum up the comments.

- Removing definitively a definition requires explicit manual removal.
- Overriding previous definitions is quite easy. See the following.

### Functions and commands:

Functions and commands need to be defined banged -> `function!`, `command!`

### autocommands

autocommands need to be cleared. I usually proceed this way:

```
augroup MyPluginNameOrFeature
  au! " <- this clears all autocommands defined in the group MyPluginNameOrFeature
  au Event pattern action
aug END
```

### Anti-reinclusion guards

Anti-reinclusion guards need to be bypassed. For instance, my plugins are usually defined this way:

```
" plugin/foobar.vim
let s:k_version = '100'
if &cp || (exists("g:loaded_foobar")
      \ && (g:loaded_foobar>= s:k_version)
      \ && !exists('g:force_reload_foobar'))
  finish
endif
let g:loaded_foobar= s:k_version
let s:cpo_save=&cpo
set cpo&vim
... plugin definitions (mappings, commands, autocommand, abbreviation)
... understand that functions are in autoload-plugin which don't have anti-reinclusion guards
let &cpo=s:cpo_save
```

This means you'll have to either increment version number before saving and reloading, or you'll need to set `g:force_reload_foobar` to 1 before reloading the script. Hence my [`:Reload`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/vim_maintain.vim) command (It's the same as the ones presented in the two other answers -- this one supports command line autocompletion relative to `'runtimepath'` option though)

### Objects (dictionaries with methods)

In the case of objects that we could create with:

```
function! namespace#make_my_object(args)
   let res = {}
   " don't write the following if you want to be able
   " to override the member function definitions when reloading the script
   " and if you want to be able to decode which function appears in 
   " the callstack
   "    :function! res.foo() abort
   "       code
   "    :endfunction
   " Instead write:
   let res.foo = function('s:foo') " with later vim versions
   let res.foo = function(s:getSNR('s:foo')) " with older vim versions

   return res
endfunction

function! s:foo() dict abort
   code
endfunction

function! s:getSNR(...) abort
  " needed to assure compatibility with old vim versions
  if !exists("s:SNR")
    let s:SNR=matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\d\+_\zegetSNR$')
  endif
  return s:SNR . (a:0>0 ? (a:1) : '')
endfunction
```

Otherwise if you have already extracted `:let o = namespace#make_my_object(42)`, re-sourcing the script won't update the definition of the methods of the object. `:Reload plugin/foobar.vim | :call o.foo()`

### Global variables

Overriding/reinitializing a variable is really easy. Just give it a new value. However if your version of vim is not recent enough, you won't be able to change the type of your data. It's easy to check how vim behaves on your side:

```
let s:foo = 'bar'
let s:foo = {}
```

If this ends up with an error, you'll may need to add an explicit `:silent! unlet s:foo`. But don't leave it in your script, once committed, if you plan to test it in tracis-CI through vim-client-server feature and vimrunner. Instead test for `if exists('s:foo') |unlet s:foo | endif` -- `:silent` is not that silent when used within a `redir` as vimrunner does.

Sometimes we do NOT want to reinitialize a variable but keep the previous value. In that case, write something like:

```
let s:foo = get(s:, 'foo', default_value)
let g:foo = get(g:, 'foo', another_default_value)
```

### Mappings, abbreviations, and menus

There isn't much to do in their case as they are automatically overridden with new definitions. The main thing to take care of is when you provide `<Plug>mappings` with default and unique keybindings to trigger them.

For instance:

```
nnoremap <silent> <Plug>(some-feature) TheActionToExecute
if !hasmapto('<Plug>(some-feature)', 'n')
  nmap <silent> <unique> <leader>default-keybinding <Plug>(some-feature)
endif
```

`<unique>`  is really useful to detect ambiguities/too many actions that  want to be bound to the same sequence of keys.

It's the same with menus: providing a new definition overrides the previous one. But binding the action to a new menu entry (name and priority) is like binding a mapping to a new key sequence: the old one isn't removed. At best you're momentarily (during your vim session) semantically overloading some trigger->action definition: there are several ways to trigger a semantically identical action. It's usually not that important.

### Misc

I haven't addressed specifically the case of ftplugins, nor other script kinds. The only difference I see is related to anti-reinclusion guards and the fact that mappings, commands, and abbreviation are buffer local in the case of ftplugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description. I've learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use the [vim-scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin written by Tim Pope.

The plugin provides a function `:Disarm`. Here's what the [doc](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease/blob/master/doc/scriptease.txt#L42-L46) says about the command:

> Attempt to disable a runtime file by removing its
>   `:map` s, `:command` s, and `:autocmd` s.  Accepts either
>   an absolute (~/.vim/plugin/scriptease.vim) or
>   runtime-relative (plugin/scriptease.vim) path.

Maybe that's not perfect because it doesn't handle the initialized variables but that could still help.

Comment: I installed the vim-scriptease plugin to see how it does all these things. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You likely don't see your changes applied because plugins usually have a multiple-inclusion guard of the form

```
if exists('g:loaded_name')
    finish
endif
let g:loaded_name = 1
```

My [ReloadScript plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1904) bypasses the usual inclusion guard variable with a simple `:ReloadScript` command.

This still won't help with incompatible mappings, renamed autocmd groups, and so on. For those cases, it's easier and way more robust to just restart Vim than trying to undo all of those changes within the current session.

Comment: I'm using the restart method instead, while checking how the vim-scriptease plugin work. I will try yours too after that. Thanks